# Is there an efficient way to form this block matrix with numpy or scipy?

Tags: numpy, matrix, scipy

[image]

A is NxN, B is NxM. They are the matrices for a dynamical system x=Ax+Bu. I could propagate the matrix using np.block(), but I hope there's a way of forming this matrix can scale based on the size of N. I was thinking maybe kronecker product np.kron() can help, but I can't think of a way. Any advice would help, and if anyone knows what this matrix is called please let me know, thanks.

EDIT: I can do the following to generate a hardcoded solution.

```
N = 3
A = np.random.random((N, N))
B = np.random.random((N, 1))
print("A:", A)
print("B:", B)
np.block([ [B, np.zeros((B.shape[0], B.shape[1]*(N-1)))],
           [A@B, B, np.zeros((B.shape[0], B.shape[1]*(N-1-1)))],
           [np.linalg.matrix_power(A,N-1)@B, np.linalg.matrix_power(A,N-1-1)@B, B]
         ] )
```

input:

```
A: [[0.35227098 0.98853832 0.42468451]
 [0.49288462 0.34457356 0.79954007]
 [0.52171255 0.63167711 0.27997043]]
B: [[0.53736681]
 [0.05086935]
 [0.42558792]]
```

output:

```
array([[0.53736681, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.05086935, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.42558792, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.42032564, 0.53736681, 0.        ],
       [0.62266266, 0.05086935, 0.        ],
       [0.43163605, 0.42558792, 0.        ],
       [0.94690357, 0.42032564, 0.53736681],
       [0.76683544, 0.62266266, 0.05086935],
       [0.73345624, 0.43163605, 0.42558792]])
```

What I am hoping to achieve is with an efficient way to generate such a matrix that scales with N, and I am able to do it with np.block() and list but it just seems to be not efficient for me.

```
mat_list = [] 
for i in range(N): # generate row
    tmp = []
    for j in range(N): # loop through A^j*B
        if j <= i:
            tmp.append(np.linalg.matrix_power(A,i-j)@B)
    if i < N-1:
        tmp.append(np.zeros((B.shape[0], B.shape[1]*(N-1-i))))
    mat_list.append(tmp)

np.block(mat_list)
```

output:

```
array([[0.53736681, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.05086935, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.42558792, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.42032564, 0.53736681, 0.        ],
       [0.62266266, 0.05086935, 0.        ],
       [0.43163605, 0.42558792, 0.        ],
       [0.94690357, 0.42032564, 0.53736681],
       [0.76683544, 0.62266266, 0.05086935],
       [0.73345624, 0.43163605, 0.42558792]])
```

Comment: Your matrix definition doesn't make sense to me.  You should really post a small sample input /output and review [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Forget about 'efficient' at the moment, and focus on making a small example work.  Then we can talk about improvements.  Any meaningful answer will have to prove itself, against your benchmark.

Comment: @user3483203 I've updated with an short example for generating such a matrix.

Comment: @hpaulj I got a small example for N=3 and the solution that can scale up with respect to N.

Comment: Look at the code for `np.block` for a discussion of speed alternatives.  Collecting pieces in a list (of lists) and doing a concatenate (or two) is common array construction.  It's not as fast as using some sort of 'broadcasted' outer operation, but that probably isn't applicable here.  `np.tri` is an example of using an 'outer' calc.  `np.kron` uses `outer` and `concatenate`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to compute the block matrices which reoccur throughout the array:

```
import itertools as it

AB = list(it.accumulate(it.chain([B], it.repeat(A, N-1)), lambda x, y: y @ x))
zero = np.zeros_like(B)
result = np.block([AB[i::-1] + [zero]*(N-1-i) for i in range(N)])
```